# What is timestamp granularity computing in pandas?

Tags: pandas, time-series

I have the following dataset

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'timestamp': pd.date_range('1/1/2020', '3/1/2020 23:59', freq='12h'), 
                   'col1': np.random.randint(100,size=122)}).\
                  sort_values('timestamp')
```

I want to compute a daily, weekly and monthly sum of the `col1`. If I use 'W' granularity for the `timestamp` column I receive a ValueError : `ValueError: <Week: weekday=6> is a non-fixed frequency` and I read that is recommended to use `7D`, `30D` etc.
My question is how pandas compute `7D` or `30D` granularity? If I add another column

```
df['timestamp2']= df.timestamp.dt.floor('30D')
df.groupby('timestamp2')[['col1']].sum()
```

I get the following result:

```
timestamp2  col1   
2019-12-10  778    
2020-01-09  3100    
2020-02-08  2470
```

Why does pandas returns those dates if my min date is Jan 1, 2020 and maximum timestamp is 1 Mar, 2020?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `origin` is the POSIX origin: **1970-01-01**. By using `.floor('30D')` the allowable values are 1970-01-01, 1970-01-31, ... and all other 30 day multiples. Your dates are close to the 608-610th multiples.

```
pd.to_datetime('1970-01-01') + pd.DateOffset(days=30*608)
#Timestamp('2019-12-10 00:00:00')

pd.to_datetime('1970-01-01') + pd.DateOffset(days=30*609)
#Timestamp('2020-01-09 00:00:00')
```

---

If what you want is instead 30D periods from your first observation, then `resample` is how you can aggregate:

```
df.resample('30D', on='timestamp')['timestamp'].agg(['min', 'max'])

                  min                 max
timestamp                                
2020-01-01 2020-01-01 2020-01-30 12:00:00    # starts from 1st date
2020-01-31 2020-01-31 2020-02-29 12:00:00
2020-03-01 2020-03-01 2020-03-01 12:00:00
```